# Is there a way to stop html warnings?

Tags: php, html

As the title states:

```
Warning: getimagesize failed to open, etc
```

Is there a way to ignore these, meaning don't print them? The reason is, I don't care basically, they are very rare, I obviously do on testing but when that is done I'd rather set the code to email me than flash a big ugly message to the user.

The question applies to any warnings by the way.

Comment: Turn off `display_errors` in php.ini or do `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` in your code.  But really you should fix the code so they aren't issued n the first place.

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php to see how to configure email logging

Comment: you can edit your php.ini and either, disable `display_errors` or change the values of `error_reporting` to not show warnings. i don't quite remember the exact setting, but you can find it right there on php.ini. anyway, you should try fixing those errors first :)

Comment: You can also use error_reporting(0); in your PHP scripts.

Comment: @Cygal how reliable is that? I've tried using the error_reporting function but it seems to get overridden most of the time.

Comment: @DavidNguyen It does work; except if you use a framework doing something nasty elsewhere. Test it on an example page. :)

Comment: It seems to me you struck a nerve with the community - I don't understand the downvotes to this question. Albeit the thing you are asking for is not a good thing to do; it doesn't make your question invalid or bad. +1 from me to help circumvent all the jerks.

Comment: Fails the "what have you tried" test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are php errors, you can turn them off by altering your PHP INI settings, search for `display_errors`

`display_errors = Off`

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different ways:

- Set a [custom error handler](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) (best way, lets you do something useful like e-mail the errors to yourself)
- `ini_set('display_errors', false);`
- Surpress errors entirely via the `@` operator: `@getimagesize(...);`

Answer (score 2):

Many ways exists, here are a few...

```
error_reporting(0); //Will hide all errors from hapenning
```

Ultimately, you could only turn off E_WARNING but that would require some boolean math to exclude only E_WARNING from the current error_reporting() setting.

The other way is to put a @ sign in front of the operations you wish to hide errors from:

```
$returnvalue = @getimagesize($params);
```

This will prevent errors from showing...

The final way is to turn off error display using:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

But this way, all errors, warnings, notices are hidden. They are still logged into the error log file though.

The last warning i might want to give you is, never code with the possibility of having an error. There is always some kind of validation you can do and SHOULD do. Turning off errors or ignoring them is usually not good and may lead to hardships later when you try to fix and problem that arose because you decided to simply hide potential errors..

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's some PHP involved here. You can change your error reporting by configuring your php.ini (the php config file) file. You can turn error reporting off, leave it on for warnings and notices, leave it on for errors or leave them on for all.

Notices and warnings will not cause major problems or keep the script from running. Fatal errors though will stop the scripts from running.

So within your php.ini file, look for this line:

error_reporting = E_ERROR, and change it to one of the following, or a combination of:

```
E_ALL             - All errors and warnings
E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
                  from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
                  intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
                  relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
                  empty string)
E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
                  initial startup
E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
```

By setting the value to `E_ERROR`, the warnings and notices will not be shown. Only the errors will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `error_reporting(0);`

in your pages or you can also use [.htaccess](http://www.bala-krishna.com/control-php-error-reporting-with-htaccess/) file and `php.ini` to set the error reporting off.